# Show the set of all functions $f : A \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is equinumerous with the power set of $A.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having some difficultly establishing a bijection from the set of functions
$ f: A\rightarrow  \{0,1\},$ to the power set of $A.$

For the case where $A$ is finite, I found that $2^{|A|}$ is the total amount of functions from $A$, and that $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}$ as well. For the cases where $A$ is denumerable or uncountable I am unsure how to proceed. I know by Cantor's theorem that $|A| < |P(A)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{0,1\}^A$ denote the set of all functions from $A$ into $\{0,1\}$ and $2^A$ denote the power set of $A$. Define a function
$$
G : \{0,1\}^A \to 2^A
$$
by
$$
G(f) = \{a\in A \mid f(a)=1\}.
$$
Argue that $G$ is a bijection.

Comment: If I have a function f* whose domain is N and for all n in N f(n) = 1, then G(f*) = N. I feel I am running into the same issue with the |P(A)| being now 2^N.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much.